# C++ Program to convert any base(2-9) to decimal

Tags: c++

This is the simple program to convert any base(2-9) to decimal.
It is completely compiled, but the output is not what I expected.
Please let me know what's the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int size_int(int num) //the number of num
{
  int n = 0;
  while(num > 0)
  {
    num = num/10;
    n = n+1;
  }
  return n;
}

int convert(int num, int b) //conver num base b to base 10
{
  int sum = 0;
  int n = size_int(num);
  while(n>0)
  {
    sum += (num/pow(10,n-1)) * (pow(b,n-1));
    n -= 1;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  int num;
  cout << "Enter a number to convert: ";
  cin >> num;

  int b;
  cout << "Enter the base of number: ";
  cin >> b;

  int sum;
  sum = convert(num, b);

  cout << "Its decimal value is: "<< sum << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Enter a number to convert: 10110
Enter the base of number: 2
Its decimal value is: 12632
This is the result when I executed.

Comment: Why are you storing the "number to convert" in an int?

Comment: @ViralTaco_ you mean the way to convert is wrong?

Comment: I didn't check. I'm just wondering why you used an int. Have you considered using a string?

Comment: Reformulate without using `pow` - won't fix a large difference but may make things more stable numerically.

Comment: @ViralTaco_ Yes, I know that one. But I just know what was wrong with mine. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Step through with your line by line debugger, and see where it deviates from how you would do it with a pen and paper. It will be obvious then.

Comment: @Bathsheba Ok, I'll try it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You calculated your current digit seems not right `num/pow(10,n-1)`.
This is my suggestion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int size_int(int num) //the number of num
{
    int n = 0;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        num = num / 10;
        n = n + 1;
    }
    return n;
}

int convert(int num, int b) //conver num base b to base 10
{
    int sum = 0;
    int n = size_int(num);
    int counter = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        int temp = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        sum += temp * (pow(b, counter));
        counter++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter a number to convert: ";
    cin >> num;

    int b;
    cout << "Enter the base of number: ";
    cin >> b;

    int sum;
    sum = convert(num, b);

    cout << "Its decimal value is: " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't like the use of `pow` (hence the downvote), or `int` as the type, but everything else looks reasonable.